# Issue with actionSheet/textfield delegate when using TAB key

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uiactionsheet

i have four Uitextfields, on one textfield i have set action sheet and three ohthers  just for text input.here is my code..

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{    

    if(textField.tag==3)// tag will be integer
    {    
        NSLog(@"ACTION SHEET WILL DISPLAY");    
        [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
        [textField resignFirstResponder];            
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Manpower", @"Admin",@"Research" ,nil];
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; 
    }

    return YES;

}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {

    if (textField.tag) {            
        UIResponder *nextField = [textField viewWithTag:(textField.tag + 1)];            
        [nextField becomeFirstResponder];            
    }

    else {            
        // Unknown field, just resign first responder.            
        [textField resignFirstResponder];            
    }

    return NO;       
}
```

now my problem is when i pressed my keyboard TAB key from any of three textfields, my action sheet is displayed! , though if i click textfields individually it works well.

Answer (score 1):

what you do is just give different tags to different textfields in xib then rather comparing to textfields name just compare tags and return NO for that textfield so keyboard will not popup when actionsheet will open like below...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{    

 if(textField.tag==your textfield tag)// tag will be integer
 {    
  NSLog(@"ACTION SHEET WILL DISPLAY");    
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];            
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Manpower", @"Admin",@"Research" ,nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view]; 
return NO;         
} 
 else
{
  return YES;
}

 }
```

let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding...!!!!!

Comment: actually i'm not using xib, i'm using hand coded textfields. and are you sure that comparing with tags instead its name will really work?

Comment: yeah man, if you are not using textfields inside xib and you have taken them programmatically then you can assign tags programmatically like txtField1.tag =3; , txtField=4; and so on...then you compare it my friend..

Comment: okay i given tags to all textfields (0-4), bt same issue... check this  http://weaklyreferenced.wordpress.com/tag/uitextfielddelegate/

i'm having same issue.

Comment: why you have just written if (textField.tag) in -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField { method..??? you are comparing nothing there...that code means every time that method will be called everty time it will go inside that if condtion...

Comment: yes, if textfield has tag then that condition will run, here just control is transfered to its next texfield with following tag...but the thing is when i press TAB key from any of three textfields i found 4to5 times my delegate called

Comment: but your every textfield has tag dude..so every time it will go in the same condition...just make if(textfield.tag==4)//for example

Comment: not working!, but is it necessary to test behavior of TAB key? as der ll b no such key in iphone!

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help you

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{    

    if(textField == dept_label)
 {    
   NSLog(@"ACTION SHEET WILL DISPLAY");    
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];            
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Manpower", @"Admin",@"Research" ,nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];         

 return NO;
} 


else
{
return YES;
}       
}
```

Comment: i tried this, bt it's still not working, action get displayed on tab key from any of three textfields and even worst is that keyboard not hiding when value selected from action sheet! :(

Comment: Did you add -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField ??

Comment: yes, i have. but it ll hide keyboard only when i press enter on that particular textfield, and for that i have to click that textfield to type, and if i click there actionsheet gets re opened !